# Feed gcc various tiny programs?

Tags: c, gcc

I need to compile various different tiny programs. (One program per .c file.) Currently I wrote a simple shell script that finds all the .c files and runs gcc on each of them. Is it possible to run gcc once and feed it the .c files, instead of running and stopping gcc again and again like this shell script does ?

```shell
find "/home/myuser/myfolder" -name "*.c" -type f |
while read filename
do
    case $filename in
        *.c)        gcc $filename -o $var ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Why is "running and stopping gcc again and again" a problem? The necessary files will be in fast filesystem caches anyway, so the process creation and destruction won't incur much overhead.

Comment: @Piskvor Ok, but it would be a better way than running gcc 100 times.

Comment: I still don't see a reason *why* running `gcc` 100 times would be bad, and running it 1 time would be *better* - in contrast to physical components, software doesn't break when you start and stop it 100 times in rapid succession.

Comment: This seems like a job for Make.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You can only compile one program/module at a time.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run gcc for each file you want to compile and not one for all.  If you include multiple c files to gcc it will try to link them all which isn't what you want.